# Error de conexión dentro de una clase

Tags: php, mysql, poo

Estoy trabajando sobre un modelo de clases y vistas, no el modelo MVC. Y estoy teniendo un error cuando quiero incluir la conexión a la base de datos.

Archivo de clases `home.php`

```
<?php

require_once 'db.php';

$conexion = new Dbh();
$conexion->connect();


class Home extends Theme{

    public function __construct(){
        $this->theme = new Theme();
    }

    public function home($tres){
        $data['page_id'] = 1;
        $data['page_title'] = 'Home';
        $this->theme->getTheme($this, 'home', $data);
    }

    public function getlist(){
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM lista";
        $stmt = $conexion->connect()->prepare($sql); // linea 24
        $stmt->execute();
        $result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        return $result;
    }

}

?>
```

Archivo de clases `db.php`

```
<?php

class Dbh{

    private $host   = 'localhost';
    private $user   = 'root';
    private $pass   = '';
    private $dbName = '';

    public function connect(){
        $dsn = 'mysql:host='.$this->host.';dbname='.$this->dbName.';charset=utf8';
        $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $this->user, $this->pass);
        $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        return $pdo;
    }
}

?>
```

Archivo theme `home.php`

```
<?php headeradmin($data); ?>

<div class="container py-5">
<h1>Home</h1>


<?php

$lista = new Home();

$dato = $lista->getlist();

foreach($dato as $row){
    echo $row['nombre'].'<br>';
}

?>

</div>

<?php footeradmin($data); ?>
```

El error que tengo es en la linea 24, me dice que no esta definido la variable `$conexion`, pero si lo esta y segundo es un fatal error también en la linea 24

> Warning: Undefined variable $conexion in...
>
> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function connect() on null in

No estoy entendiendo que estoy haciendo mal. Agradezco la ayuda de antemano.

Comment: Añada la línea donde *instancias* la conexión dentro del ```public function __construct(){ $this->conexion = new Dbh();  etc.. }```.

Comment: Gracias por responder. Pero la clase Dbh no esta heredada y tengo otro error: `Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Home::connect() in...`

Comment: `$conexion` está definida en el scope (ámbito) **global**, no en el de **clase**. O la llevas dentro de la clase heredando desde la clase `Dbh`, o usas [global](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.variables.scope.php), o creas la instancia conexión dentro de la clase. Otra opción es hacer una [herencia múltiple] declarando `Dbh` como [trait](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.oop5.traits.php)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El primer error es porque tu variable `$conexion` no esta definida en tu *class* **Home**, para solucionarlo, puedes instanciarlo en el **__constructor** y posterior trabajar con el usando `$this->conexion`.

El segundo error, al no existir la conexión tu **sentencia preparada** falla.

**Posible ejemplo:**

```
<?php

require_once 'db.php';

class Home extends Theme{

    private $conexion;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->theme = new Theme();

        // Incluir conexion
        // 
        // Instancias la clase conexion
        $con = new Dbh();
        // Obtenemos conexion
        $this->conexion = $con->connect();
    }

    public function home($tres){
        $data['page_id'] = 1;
        $data['page_title'] = 'Home';
        $this->theme->getTheme($this, 'home', $data);
    }

    public function getlist(){
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM lista";
        $stmt = $this->conexion->prepare($sql); // linea 24, lo cambie por $this->conexion
        $stmt->execute();
        $result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        return $result;
    }

}
```

Comment: Estaba pensando utilizar interfaces para heredar mas de una clase. Otra opción fue crear la función de conexión dentro de la clase, pero mi idea era utilizarla de esta forma, cada vez que se crea un archivo de clase nuevo y si respectiva vista. Muchas gracias!

Comment: Si, existen varias opciones, podrías también heredar. Por ejemplo para heredar a tu class **Theme**, si este tiene **__construct()** podrías usar en tu clase hijo **Home** ```public function __construct() { parent::construct(); }```, así te evitas tener que instanciarlo, aquí te dejo el manual: https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.oop5.decon.php
Suerte y me alegro de que te funciono. Un saludo

Comment: Muchas gracias por la info y por tu tiempo. Saludos!