# Error en include php

Tags: php

estoy intentando hacer un inicio de sesión en php. He creado un archivo "config.php" donde hago la conexión con la base de datos de sql para así incluirlo fácilmente en los archivos que los requieran.
Resulta que en el fichero llamado "usuario.php" me da un error en uno de estos includes, el mensaje es el siguiente:

```
! ) Notice: Undefined variable: conexion in /home/pw77389915/public_html/pe2/exposiciones/usuario.php on line 9
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0001  383264  {main}( )   .../index.php:0
2   0.0022  428840  Usuario->existeUsuario( )   .../index.php:26
```

Y esta es la estructura de mi archivo "usuario.php" es:

```
    <?php
    include("config.php");
    
    class Usuario{
        private $usuario;
        private $nombre; 
        public function existeUsuario($user, $password){
            $md5password = md5($password);
            $consultaSQL = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE usuario =:user AND contrasenia =:md5password";
            $sentenciaSQL = $conexion->prepare($consultaSQL);
            $sentenciaSQL->execute(['user' => $user, 'pass' => $md5password]);

            if($sentenciaSQL->rowCount()){
                return true;
            }
            else{
                return false;
            }
        }

        public function setUsuario($user){
            $consultaSQL = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE usuario = :user";
            $consultaSQL->execute(['user' => $user]);

            foreach($consultaSQL as $currentUser){
                $this->nombre = $currentUser['nombre'];
                $this->usuario = $currentUser['usuario'];
            }
        }

        public function getNombre(){
            return $this->nombre;
        }
    }

?>
```

Y la de "config.php":

```
<?php
    try {
        $dsn = "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=db77389915_pw2122";
        $usuario =  "pw77389915";
        $password = "77389915";
        $conexion = new PDO($dsn,$usuario,$password);
        $conexion->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
    } catch ( PDOException $e ) { echo "Conexión fallida: " . $e->getMessage(); }
?>
```

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Fíjate que solamente incluyes a tu archivo conexión, pero ```$conexion``` no está definida en tu class **Usuario**. Quizás te puede ayudar esta respuesta: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/540174/error-de-conexi%c3%b3n-dentro-de-una-clase/540194#540194

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema se debe a que la variable `$conexion` está definida fuera del ámbito de la función.

Para que `PHP` entienda que estas haciendo referencia a una variable definida fuera de dicho contexto es necesario usar [`global`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.variables.scope.php#language.variables.scope.global)

Ejemplo:

```php
public function existeUsuario($user, $password){
    global $conexion; // <- ACA

    $md5password = md5($password);
    $consultaSQL = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE usuario =:user AND contrasenia =:md5password";
    $sentenciaSQL = $conexion->prepare($consultaSQL);
    $sentenciaSQL->execute(['user' => $user, 'pass' => $md5password]);
    // ... resto del código
```

---

Esta es una solución que no escala, es decir, en cada método vas a tener que realizar dicha acción. Sería recomendable mover dicha lógica al constructor de la clase, o aún mejor crear una clase que maneje la conexión y tu clase `Usuario` la extienda.

Comment: Muchas gracias, ya funciona.

Answer (score 1):

Dado que estas trabajando con objetos, creo que lo correcto seria que conexion fuera una clase. Algo como:

```
<?php
    class Conexion {
    private $conexion = null;

    public function __construct() 
    {
        try {
            $dsn = "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=db77389915_pw2122";
            $usuario =  "pw77389915";
            $password = "77389915";
            $this->conexion = new PDO($dsn,$usuario,$password);
            $this->conexion->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION     );
        } catch ( PDOException $e ) { echo "Conexión fallida: " .    $e->getMessage(); 
        }
    }

    public function getConexion() {
        return $this-conexion;
    }
}
```

Ahora, tu clase usuario podria componer la clase, y en su constructor poner algo como:

```
<?php
    include("conexion.php");
    
    class Usuario{
        private $usuario;
        private $nombre; 
        private $conexion;

        public  function __construct() 
        {
            $this-conexion = new Conexion();
        }

        public function existeUsuario($user, $password){
            $md5password = md5($password);
            $consultaSQL = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE usuario =:user AND contrasenia =:md5password";
            $sentenciaSQL = $this->conexion->prepare($consultaSQL);
            $sentenciaSQL->execute(['user' => $user, 'pass' => $md5password]);

            return $sentenciaSQL->rowCount();
        }
    }
```

Nota: Seria mas correcto que el objeto usuario no hiciera un new de Conexion, sino que fuera inyectado por dependencia en el constructor. Dado que parece que estas trabajando con php directo, te plantearia que revisaras temas de inyección de dependencias, principios solid, composición sobre herencia...

Comment: Muchas gracias, ya me ha funcionado.